# getting error on spring webflow junit

Tags: spring, junit, spring-webflow-2

I am new to spring webflow and start  writting unit test cases for the webflow and getting the following error.I am struggling to write the test case as its mix with decision state,action state view state and subflow I didn't find any suitable reference so far.I have tried so many possible ways and struggling to get the concept can you please help me understand what mistake I am doing

Error

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@1d8e2eea targetAction = [SetAction@240139e1 name = sourceSiteId, value = flowScope.regform.sid], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'ssoerrorredirect' of flow 'regEnroll-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:154)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
    at org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractFlowExecutionTests.startFlow(AbstractFlowExecutionTests.java:121)
    at com.shc.ecom.test.usr.TestRegEnroll.testStartFlow(TestRegEnroll.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An ELException occurred getting the value for expression 'flowScope.regform.sid' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.SetAction.doExecute(SetAction.java:55)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'sid' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    ... 35 more
```

webflow xml>

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd" 
     start-state="confirmsuccess">

    <var name="regform" class="com.test.ecoms.user.form.Regform" />
    <!-- <input-mapper> <input-attribute name="service" /> <input-attribute 
        name="regform" /> <input-attribute name="success" /> </input-mapper> <start-state 
        idref="confirmsuccess" /> -->

    <input name="service" />
    <input name="regform" />
    <input name="success" />

    <decision-state id="confirmsuccess">
        <if test="flowScope.success!=null" then="serviceticketvalidation"
            else="saveQueryParamInSession" />
    </decision-state>
    <decision-state id="serviceticketvalidation">
        <if test="flowScope.success=='yes'" then="sywNumAction" else="ssoerrorredirect" />
    </decision-state>


    <!-- <action-state id="enterCustInfo"> <action bean="regEnrollFormAction" 
        method="setupForm" > </action> <transition on="success" to="renderform"/> 
        </action-state> -->

    <!-- save query parameter in session -->
    <action-state id="saveQueryParamInSession">
        <evaluate expression="saveQueryParamInSession" />
        <transition on="success" to="renderform" />
    </action-state>


    ......
</flow>
```

Test Cases

```
public class TestRegEnroll extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {

    private SavingQueryParamInSessionAction savingQueryParamInSession;
    private Event event;
    RequestContext contextRequest;


    protected void setUp() {
        savingQueryParamInSession = EasyMock.createMock("savingQueryParamInSession",
                SavingQueryParamInSessionAction.class);
        event =  EasyMock.createMock("event",Event.class);
        contextRequest =  EasyMock.createMock("request",RequestContext.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
        return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/usr/flows/regEnroll-flow.xml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {
        builderContext.registerBean("savingQueryParamInSession", savingQueryParamInSession);


    }

    public void testStartFlow() throws Exception {


        MockExternalContext externalContext = new MockExternalContext();
        MockRequestContext context=new MockRequestContext();
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();
        input.put("success", "renderform");
        input.put("flowScope.regform.sid", 3);
        input.put("clienthost", "qa.ecom.sears.com:4380");


        EasyMock.expect(savingQueryParamInSession.doExecute(contextRequest)).andReturn(event );
        EasyMock.replay(savingQueryParamInSession); 

        startFlow(input, externalContext);
        assertCurrentStateEquals("renderform");


    }

    public void testStartRenderFormFlow() throws Exception {

    }

    private Regform createRegistrationForm() {
        Regform regform = new Regform();
        regform.setEmail("20130410111@gmail.com");
        regform.setLname("mike");
        regform.setFname("sun");
        regform.setPassword("test11");
        regform.setSid("3");
        regform.setZip("60179");
        return regform;
    }

}
```

ModifyTestCase

```
    public class TestRegEnrollFlow extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {

    SavingQueryParamInSessionAction savingQueryParamInSessionAction = new SavingQueryParamInSessionAction();

    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
        return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/usr/flows/regEnroll-flow.xml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {
        //I Have tried even mocking using Easy Mock
        /*savingQueryParamInSession = EasyMock.createMock("savingQueryParamInSession",
                SavingQueryParamInSessionAction.class);
        event =  EasyMock.createMock("event",Event.class);
        contextRequest =  EasyMock.createMock("request",RequestContext.class);*/
        builderContext.registerBean("savingQueryParamInSession", savingQueryParamInSessionAction);

        builderContext.registerBean("sywNumSetupAction", new SywNumSetupAction());
        builderContext.registerBean("ssoGatewayService", new SSOGatewayServiceImpl());
        builderContext.registerBean("regEnrollFormAction", new RegEnrollFormAction());

    }

    public void testAction() {
        MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();
        input.put("service", "");
        input.put("regForm", createRegistrationForm());
        //this is the line where we are changing the state flow
        input.put("success", "success");
        startFlow(input, ctx);

        assertFlowExecutionActive();
        assertCurrentStateEquals("renderform");
        Object regForm = getFlowAttribute("regForm");
        assertTrue(regForm instanceof Regform);
        assertTrue(((Regform) regForm).getLname().equals("mike"));
    }

    private Regform createRegistrationForm() {
        Regform regform = new Regform();
        regform.setEmail("20130410111@gmail.com");
        regform.setLname("mike");
        regform.setFname("sun");
        regform.setPassword("test11");
        regform.setSid("3");
        regform.setZip("60179");
        return regform;
    }

}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@376a0d86 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@62656be4 expression = saveQueryParamInSession, resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'saveQueryParamInSession' of flow 'regEnroll-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
    at org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractFlowExecutionTests.startFlow(AbstractFlowExecutionTests.java:121)
    at com.shc.ecom.test.usr.TestRegEnrollFlow.testAction(TestRegEnrollFlow.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'saveQueryParamInSession' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
input.put("flowScope.regform.sid", 3);
```

by

```
input.put("regform", createRegistrationForm());
```

Comment: thanks for input I have that there is another error is coming related to execution of action state I have copied the error above can you please let me know the cause for this and also can you please explain about external context MockRequestContext

Comment: last error shown above comes in when i assign "success" as null and if i assign "succuess"  any " value" it will go to end state. To make a note saveQueryParamSesssion is returning event("succes")

Comment: @rptmat55 I have got successfully ran 1 test case  but again I have stucked in one problem can you please have a look in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010531/not-able-to-get-the-flow-scope-variable-from-one-state-transition-to-another-stat