# not able to get the flow scope variable from one state transition to another state transition junit

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

When I transit from view state to decision state or action state all the input set is lost while transitioning to another state. How to do I get the flow scope variable for decision state or action state  on transitioning from view state to decision state and action state in junit ?

In my flow definition right now I am in view state when I set the event Id as **submit** it moves to **registerEnroll** decision state where it needs `flowScope.regform.loyaltyLookUp` value. When I see the **flow execution** variable map there is nothing inside apart from **RegForm** object, even though I have set variable  in `MutableAttributeMap`.

How to set the flow scope variable which will be always  available on transitioning to state  on junit test case for spring webflow?

In **second test case** flow is going to else part of decision state even though I have provide `flowScope.regform.loyaltyLookUp` in input. What mistake I am doing I am not able to figure out .

xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd" 
     start-state="confirmsuccess">

    <var name="regform" class="com.shc.ecom.usr.form.Regform" />
    <var name="enrollresponse" class="com.shc.ecom.usr.service.adapter.ResponseVO" />

    <!-- <input-mapper> <input-attribute name="service" /> <input-attribute 
        name="regform" /> <input-attribute name="success" /> </input-mapper> <start-state 
        idref="confirmsuccess" /> -->

    <input name="service" />
    <input name="regform" />
    <input name="success" />
     <input name="enrollresponse"/> 


    <decision-state id="confirmsuccess">
        <if test="flowScope.success!=null" then="serviceticketvalidation"
            else="saveQueryParamInSession" />
    </decision-state>
    <decision-state id="serviceticketvalidation">
        <if test="flowScope.success=='yes'" then="sywNumAction" else="ssoerrorredirect" />
    </decision-state>


    <!-- <action-state id="enterCustInfo"> <action bean="regEnrollFormAction" 
        method="setupForm" > </action> <transition on="success" to="renderform"/> 
        </action-state> -->

    <!-- save query parameter in session -->
    <action-state id="saveQueryParamInSession">
        <evaluate expression="saveQueryParamInSession.doExecute(flowRequestContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="renderform" />
    </action-state>


    <view-state id="renderform" view="/regenroll"  >
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="regEnrollFormAction.setupForm(flowRequestContext)" />
                <set name="flowScope.sourceSite" value="requestParameters.sid" /> <!-- scope="flow" -->
                <set name="flowScope.service" value="requestParameters.service" />
                <set name="flowScope.clienthost" value="requestParameters.clienthost" />
                <set name="flowScope.target" value="requestParameters.target" />
                <set name="flowScope.switchForm" value="requestParameters.switchForm" />
                <set name="flowScope.oldlogin" value="requestParameters.oldlogin" />
                <set name="flowScope.emailId" value="requestParameters.emailId" />
                <set name="flowScope.confirmEmail" value="requestParameters.emailConfirm" />
                <set name="flowScope.fname" value="requestParameters.fname" />
                <set name="flowScope.lname" value="requestParameters.lname" />
                <set name="flowScope.zipCode" value="requestParameters.zip" />
                <set name="flowScope.modifyservice" value="requestParameters.modifyservice" />
                <set name="flowScope.ocpPage" value="requestParameters.ocpPage" />
                <set name="flowScope.fullpage" value="requestParameters.fullpage" />
                <set name="flowScope.emailValidateFlag" value="requestParameters.emailValidateFlag" />
                <set name="flowScope.mode" value="requestParameters.mode" />
                <set name="flowScope.phone" value="requestParameters.phone" />
                <set name="flowScope.number" value="requestParameters.number" />
                <set name="flowScope.irp" value="requestParameters.irp" />
                <set name="flowScope.sywmax" value="requestParameters.sywmax" /> 
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="submit" to="registerEnroll">
          <evaluate expression="regEnrollFormAction.bindAndValidate(flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <decision-state id="registerEnroll">
        <if test="flowScope.regform.loyaltyLookUp!=null" then="processEnroll"
            else="activateEnroll" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="processEnroll">
        <evaluate
            expression="ssoGatewayService.register(flowScope.regform,externalContext)" result="flowScope.enrollresponse" result-type="com.shc.ecom.usr.service.adapter.ResponseVO" />
            <transition on="success" to="postenroll" />
    </action-state>


    <decision-state id="postenroll">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode ==200" then="ccenroll"
            else="enrollerror" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="ccenroll">
        <if test="flowScope.regform.craftsmanAffinity!=null" then="ccAffinityUpdate"
            else="go_to_login_flow" />
    </decision-state>


    <action-state id="ccAffinityUpdate">
        <evaluate
            expression="ssoGatewayService.updateCCAffinity(flowScope.regform, flowScope.enrollresponse)"
            result="enrollresponse" />
            <transition on="success" to="postccupdate" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="postccupdate">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode==200" then="go_to_login_flow"
            else="ccupdateerror" />
    </decision-state>
    <decision-state id="enrollerror">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse.existingUserInd!=null" then="existingUserLogin"
            else="captchaValidation" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="captchaValidation">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse.errorCode eq '401.1'" then="captchaValidationError"
            else="loyaltydown" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="loyaltydown">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse.loyaltyDown!=null" then="loyaltydownerror"
            else="showerror" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="activateEnroll">
        <evaluate expression="ssoGatewayService.onlineActivation(flowScope.regform, requestParameters.clienthost,
        externalContext, requestParameters.mode, requestParameters.number, requestParameters.phone)"
         result = "enrollresponse" />
        <transition on="success" to="postenroll" />
    </action-state>

    <subflow-state id="go_to_login_flow" subflow="shclogin-flow">
        <input value="flowScope.regform.password" name="logonPassword"/>
        <input value="flowScope.regform.email" name="loginId"/>
        <input value="flowScope.regform.sid" name="sourceSiteId"/>
        <input value="flowScope.regform.service" name="service"/>
        <input value="flowScope.regform.redirectUrl" name="redirectUrl"/>
        <input value="flowScope.reglogin" name="reglogin"/>
        <input value="flowScope.enrollresponse" name="enrollresponse"/>

        <transition on="finish" to="process_and_redirect" />
        <transition on="redirect" to="process_and_redirect" />
        <transition on="sendtickettomodal_reg" to="sendtickettomodal">
            <set name="clienthost" value="requestParameters.clienthost" /> <!--  scope="flow"  -->
        </transition>
        <transition on="pickup_error_redirect_reg" to="ssoerrorredirect" />
        <transition on="pickup_error_redirect_login" to="ssoerrorredirect" />
    </subflow-state>

    <!-- 
        <attribute-mapper>
            <input-mapper>
                <mapping source="${flowScope.regform.email}" target="loginId" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.regform.password}" target="logonPassword" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.regform.sid}" target="sourceSiteId" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.regform.service}" target="service" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.regform.redirectUrl}" target="redirectUrl" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.reglogin}" target="reglogin" />
                <mapping source="${flowScope.enrollresponse}" target="enrollresponse" />
            </input-mapper>
        </attribute-mapper>
     -->


    <action-state id="sywNumAction">
        <evaluate expression="sywNumSetupAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="process_and_redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="process_and_redirect" view="/successconfirmation">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="sourceSiteId" value="flowScope.regform.sid" />
            <set name="sywrNumber" value="flowScope.sywrNumber" />
            <set name ="softLinkFlow" value="requestParameters.softLinkFlow" />
            <set name ="fullpage" value="requestParameters.fullpage" />
            <set name="targetUrl" value="requestParameters.targetUrl" />
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>

    <view-state id="showerror" view="/displayerror">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="errorCode" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode" />
            <set name="responseString" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseString" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>
    <view-state id="captchaValidationError" view="/displayerror">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="errorCode" value="401.1" />
            <set name="responseString" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.errorDescription" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>
    <view-state id="loyaltydownerror" view="/displayerror">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="errorCode" value="500.2" />
            <set name="responseString" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseString" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>
    <end-state id="existingUserLogin" view="/existingUserLogin">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="returnCode" value="'500.110'" />
            <set name="clienthost" value="requestParameters.clienthost" />
            <set name="emailId" value="flowScope.regform.email" />
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>

    <view-state id="ccupdateerror" view="/ccEnrollError">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="returnCode" value="'500.111'" />
            <set name="clienthost" value="requestParameters.clienthost" />
            <set name="emailId" value="flowScope.regform.email" />
        </on-entry>
    </view-state>

    <!-- redirect the next step from login flow -->
    <end-state id="ssoerrorredirect" view="/successconfirmationwithssoerror">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="sourceSiteId" value="flowScope.regform.sid" />
            <set name="sywrNumber" value="flowScope.sywrNumber" />
            <set name="softLinkFlow" value="requestParameters.softLinkFlow" />
            <set name="fullpage" value="requestParameters.fullpage" />
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>

    <!-- adding sywmax parameter for registration flow -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodal" view="/displayserviceticketandcookie">
        <output value="requestScope.syw" name="sywmax"/>
    </end-state>

        <!--  
            <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.syw" x } target="sywmax" />
        </output-mapper>
         -->

    <global-transitions>
        <transition to="showerror"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException" />
        <transition to="showerror"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedSsoServiceException" />
        <transition to="showerror"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedServiceException" />
        <transition to="showerror"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException" />
    </global-transitions>
    <!-- <bean-import resource="regenroll-beans.xml" /> -->
</flow>
```

Test case

Second Test is failing

```
public class TestRegEnrollFlow extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {

    SavingQueryParamInSessionAction saveQueryParamInSession;
    SSOGatewayServiceImpl ssoGatewayService;


    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
        return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/usr/flows/regEnroll-flow.xml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {
        // I Have tried even mocking using Easy Mock
        saveQueryParamInSession = EasyMock.createMock("saveQueryParamInSession", SavingQueryParamInSessionAction.class);
        ssoGatewayService = EasyMock.createMock("ssoGatewayService", SSOGatewayServiceImpl.class);

        builderContext.registerBean("saveQueryParamInSession", saveQueryParamInSession);
        builderContext.registerBean("sywNumSetupAction", new SywNumSetupAction());
        builderContext.registerBean("ssoGatewayService", ssoGatewayService);
        builderContext.registerBean("regEnrollFormAction", new RegEnrollFormAction());

    }

    public void testAction() {
        MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();

        input.put("service", "");
        input.put("regform", createRegistrationForm());
        // this is the line where we are changing the state flow
        input.put("success", null);

        input.put("externalContext", ctx);
    input.put("enrollresponse.responseCode", 200);
        input.put("regform.craftsmanAffinity", "any");

        startFlow(input, ctx);

        assertFlowExecutionActive();
        assertCurrentStateEquals("renderform");
        assertResponseWrittenEquals("/regenroll", ctx);

    }



    public void testREgForm() throws Exception {
        setCurrentState("renderform");
        MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();
        context.putRequestParameter("sid", "3");
        context.putRequestParameter("service", "qa.ecom.s.com:4380");
        context.putRequestParameter("clienthost", "qa.ecom.s.com:4380");
        context.putRequestParameter("target", "http://qa.ecom.sears.com:4380/?storeId=10153&catalogId=12605");
        context.putRequestParameter("switchForm", "Donald");
        context.putRequestParameter("oldlogin", "Donald");
        context.putRequestParameter("emailId", "jadiya@gmail.com");
        context.putRequestParameter("emailConfirm", "jadiya@gmail.com");
        context.putRequestParameter("fname", "Ankur");
        context.putRequestParameter("lname", "Jadiya");
        context.putRequestParameter("zip", "56005");
        context.putRequestParameter("modifyservice", "no");
        context.putRequestParameter("ocpPage", "no");
        context.putRequestParameter("fullpage", "no");
        context.putRequestParameter("emailValidateFlag", "true");
        context.putRequestParameter("mode", "active");
        context.putRequestParameter("phone", "8884911391");
        context.putRequestParameter("number", "883427");
        context.putRequestParameter("irp", "true");
        context.putRequestParameter("sywmax", "1234567");
        context.putRequestParameter("enrollresponse.responseCode","200");






        FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecution();
        FlowSession session = flowExecution.getActiveSession();
        //flowExecution.getConversationScope().put("flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode", 200);
        session.getScope().put("flowScope.regform.loyaltyLookUp", true);
        //session.getScope().put("flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode", "200");
    //  session.getScope().put("flowScope.enrollresponse", 200);
        //session.getScope().put("responseCode", 200);
        session.getScope().put("flowScope.regform.craftsmanAffinity", "check");
        /*session.getScope().put("enrollresponse.responseCode", 200);*/
      //  session..put("flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode", 200);
        updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);

        ResponseVO value = new ResponseVO(200, "success");
        session.getScope().put("enrollresponse", value);
        session.getScope().put("flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode", value);
        context.setEventId("submit");
    //  EasyMock.expect(ssoGatewayService.register(createRegistrationForm(), context)).andReturn(value);

        flowExecution.resume(context);
        assertCurrentStateEquals("showerror");


    }

    private Regform createRegistrationForm() {
        Regform regform = new Regform();
        regform.setEmail("20130410111@gmail.com");
        regform.setLname("mike");
        regform.setFname("sun");
        regform.setPassword("test11");
        regform.setSid("3");
        regform.setZip("60179");
        regform.setLoyaltyLookUp(true);

        return regform;
    }

}
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.setValue(SpringELExpression.java:117)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:80)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1010E:(pos 0): Property or field 'enrollresponse' cannot be set on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.writeProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:270)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.setValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:159)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.setValue(SpelExpression.java:411)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.setValue(SpringELExpression.java:114)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting this property:

```
input.put("enrollresponse.responseCode", "200");
```

but:

1. I don't see it anywhere in your flow (maybe in the part you omitted)
2. You have to first create the enrollresponse object before setting "responseCode" on it. I think that is causing the error you are having

[EDIT]

3. you also need to specify the scope for variable in `<set>` element (showrror state). replace:

   ```
   <set name="errorCode" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode" />
   ```

   by

   ```
   <set name="viewScope.errorCode" value="flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode" />
   ```

fix all those issues and try again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have appended some line of code where enrollresponse is using its actually returned by action class and we are catching it as a result. Even though I have set the value enroll.responseCode in session scope still it's not able to pick it up can you please test my second test case and the flow

Comment: actually when i debug the code this error is coming org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An ELException occurred getting the value for expression 'flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode eq '200'' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]

Comment: did you try setting enrollresponse before setting enrollresponse.responseCode?

Comment: remove all session stuff, don't set anything with enrollresponse and tell me what you get

Comment: I have commented out the session stuff for response code and added the two lines in xml `<var name="enrollresponse"class="com.shc.ecom.usr.service.adapter.ResponseVO" />`and `<input name="enrollresponse"/>` but following error is coming `SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'responseCode' cannot be found on null`  you can see the second test case and xml above as well

Comment: what you added won't change anything, because you are overriding enrollresponse in your flow with the `methodssoGatewayService.register(flowScope.regform,externalContext)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121360/discussion-between-rptmat57-and-henrycharles).

Comment: Did you get any chance to look into it I am not getting any clue what mistake is happening .

Comment: added 3rd bullet point, you need to specify scope of variables in your showError state

Comment: add viewScope on all the names of variables in `<set>` elements of the state

Comment: is there any change we need to do second test case that is testREgForm()

Comment: if you see decision state postenroll there is line flowScope.enrollresponse.responseCode ==200 which is causing issue because of which its going to global transition state and then to view scope "showerror". How can  i make this as true what value exactly I need to set in testcase so that i can make this condition as true

Comment: FYI when i debug I am getting TypedValue: 'null' of [null] for responseCode in PropertyOrFieldReference

Comment: [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121360/discussion-between-rptmat57-and-henrycharles)