# Junit Testing subflow with multile transition inside it

Tags: junit4, spring-webflow-2

Hi I have  multiple transition state inside the  subflow how to test those transition. And when my flow encountered first transition state inside subflow its throwing `org.springframework.webflow.engine.NoMatchingTransitionException: No transition found on occurence of event 'process_and_redirect' in state 'go_to_login_flow' of flow 'regEnroll-flow' -- valid transitional criteria are array<TransitionCriteria>[finish, redirect, sendtickettomodal_reg, pickup_error_redirect_reg, pickup_error_redirect_login] -- likely programmer error, check the set of TransitionCriteria for this state`

Then Error is delegating to global transitioning tag where its going to showerror view page. I need to write the test case for the subflow and I am not getting how to test it .

This is the link where my webflow is defined
[not able to get the flow scope variable from one state transition to another state transition junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010531/not-able-to-get-the-flow-scope-variable-from-one-state-transition-to-another-sta)

this is what I tried so far 
mocked the subflow and registered inside

```
@Override
protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {
    // I Have tried even mocking using Easy Mock
    saveQueryParamInSession = EasyMock.createMock("saveQueryParamInSession", SavingQueryParamInSessionAction.class);
    ssoGatewayService = EasyMock.createMock("ssoGatewayService", SSOGatewayServiceImpl.class);
    sywNumSetupAction = EasyMock.createMock("sywNumSetupAction", SywNumSetupAction.class);
    regEnrollFormAction = EasyMock.createMock("regEnrollFormAction", RegEnrollFormAction.class);

    builderContext.registerBean("saveQueryParamInSession", saveQueryParamInSession);

    builderContext.registerBean("sywNumSetupAction", sywNumSetupAction);
    builderContext.registerBean("ssoGatewayService", ssoGatewayService);
    builderContext.registerBean("regEnrollFormAction", regEnrollFormAction);
    Flow mockDetailFlow = new Flow("shclogin-flow");
    mockDetailFlow.setInputMapper(new Mapper() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public MappingResults map(Object source, Object target) {

            return null;
        }
    });

    new EndState(mockDetailFlow, "process_and_redirect");
    builderContext.registerSubflow(mockDetailFlow);

}
```

Test Case

```
public void testsubflowTransition() throws Exception {

        setCurrentState("renderform");
        MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();

        FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecution();
        FlowSession session = flowExecution.getActiveSession();

        Regform regform = createRegistrationForm();
        session.getScope().put("regform", regform);
        session.getScope().put("reglogin", "yes");
        ResponseVO value = new ResponseVO(200, "success");
        updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);
        context.setEventId("submit");
        EasyMock.expect(ssoGatewayService.register(regform, context)).andReturn(value);
        EasyMock.expect(ssoGatewayService
                .updateCCAffinity(flowExecution.getActiveSession().getScope().get("regform", Regform.class), value))
                .andReturn(value);
        EasyMock.replay(ssoGatewayService);
        flowExecution.resume(context);
        setCurrentState("go_to_login_flow");
        context.setEventId("sendtickettomodal_reg");
        flowExecution.resume(context);
```

Comment: @rptmat57 can you please look into it

Comment: hmm. I just ran your test and it passed

Comment: the test seems truncated. did you forget to post some of it? is `flowExecution.resume(context);` the last line of your test?

Comment: @rptmat57 I had successfully running test cases If I will copy all my test can you review those if you don't mind as I am new to these test cases I am not sure about whether the way I am doing is upto the standard or not